# Office.js select text and replace it with a ContentControl

Tags: javascript, office-js

I have the following use case using Office.js:

- search for some text with `body.search()`
- after finding the text, can be multiple occurrences, iterate through them and replace them with a ContentControl with a different content

The search part is easy, but I'm not sure about the second part. Inserting a ContentControl to the cursor position and manipulating it's HTML content isn't an issue, but I'm not sure if it's possible to programmatically select a string and then replace it with other content. Is it?
Or should I somehow create a ContentControl around the selected text and then just manipulate it's HTML content?

This is my code so far, within `Word.run`:

```
const res = context.document.body.search('[{]*[}]', {matchWildCards: true});
context.load(res, 'text');

return context.sync().then(() => {
  const citeKeys = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < res.items.length; i += 1) {
    // iterate through found strings by accessing res.items[i].text
  }
// ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you searched the strings, body.search will return a collection to you and you can loop the range collection and call `range.insertText("...", "replace")`. This `insertText` method will also return a `range` and then you can call `range.insertContentControl` on it. I think this will help you achieve the goal.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I will give it a go and then come back to this thread.