# Office - js create paragraph copy

Tags: office365, office-js

how is it possible to duplicate text in document?

for example, I have implemented searching in document for some word, and then I'm changing this word to another. But now I want to clone first text (or paragraph), in which I'm searching special word, and just insert it with changed words next to first it's version....

In document it would be like that:

```
Lorium ipsum cat scater
Lorium ipsum dog scater
```

In this example searched text is 'cat' and replacement is 'cat', so how I can do this with Office-js, because I can't found any examples in documentation =( ?

next code is my search function:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
            var doc = context.document;
            var searchResult = doc.body.search("cat", { matchCase: false });

            context.load(searchResult, 'text, font') //Queue a commmand to load the results.
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < searchResult.items.length; i++) {
                    var censoredText = "dog"
                    searchResult.items[i].font.highlightColor = "#FFFF00";
                    searchResult.items[i].select();
                    var selected = doc.getSelection()

                    selected.insertText(censoredText, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
                    //deselect selected and move cursor to the end
                    searchResult.items[i].select('end');
                }
            });
        })
            .catch(errorHandler)
```

**EDIT:** May be it is difficult to understand my problem... 
the problem is second - I need to copy main paragraph `Lorium ipsum cat scater` and insert it on second line but with changed word `Lorium ipsum dog scater`

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

After you searched the strings and call `range.insertText("....","replace")`. This insertText method will also return a range and then you can call `range.insertContentControl` on it.

For more information, please refer the following link:

[Office.js select text and replace it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943435/office-js-select-text-and-replace-it-with-a-contentcontrol)

[Using an Office Add-In to search and replace data](https://xomino.com/2016/08/28/using-an-office-add-in-to-search-and-replace-data-in-a-word-document/)

**Update:** >>Copy main paragraph in document?

Please refer the following code:

```
  const copyToClipboard = str => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
};
```

For more information, please review the link as below:

[Copying text](https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f)